# Java Timezone auto-conversion?

Tags: java, date, playframework

Recently I am working with SimpleDateFormat and encountered an interesting problem (please see the code below):

```
Sample sampleOne = new Sample():
sampleOne.date = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" ).parse( "19880428");
Sample sampleTwo= new Sample():
sampleOne.date = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" ).parse( "19881225");
```

The date in sampleOne displayed as BST while sampleTwo's date displayed as GMT. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: usually date object doesn't have timezone attached, and they display the date/time in local timezone.. are you sure both have different timezone info?

Comment: How are you displaying the dates? Note that 28 April is during summer time, and 25 December is during winter time.

Comment: Basically I used a debugger to look at the value and i saw that the date of sampleTwo is Sun Dec 25 00:00:00 GMT 1988, while the other is Thu Apr 28 00:00:00 BST 1988

Comment: They both get converted according to the right timezone for your location, on the date in question.  That's why you have to be really careful adding and subtracting dates - sometimes an extra hour creeps in and messes things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your default Locale is "timezone Europe/London",

In the summer, London is at the British Summer Time (BST) timezone. In the winter, it's at the GMT timezone. Thats why you are getting different results.

Comment: Oh yes! I am such an idiot! GMT is the timezone for UK in Winter! Thank you so much!